# Debootstrapping karmic powerpc arch results in error?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, powerpc, debootstrap

I'm trying to retrieve the powerpc arch of Karmic Koala with the following command:

```
sudo debootstrap --arch powerpc karmic /home/xbmc/karmic http://archive.ubuntulinux.org/ubuntu
```

However, I get the following error:

```
E: No such script: /usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/karmic
```

I used the debootstrap from the official repo:

```
debootstrap --version
debootstrap 1.0.12
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This user found a solution [on LinuxQuestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/debootstrapping-karmic-powerpc-arch-results-in-error-765376/).

- To avoid the missing script, create a symbolic link to one of the existing scripts.  Another user suggested linking to the *gutsy* script, and apparently that worked:

  ```
  cd /usr/share/debootstrap/scripts
  ln -s gutsy karmic
  ```
- The mirror used in the *debootstrap* commandline (http://archive.ubuntulinux.org/ubuntu) is wrong, since that mirror only includes x86/x64 packages.  Instead, http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports should be used.  This user also needed the `--foreign` option.  The final command is:

  ```
  debootstrap --foreign --arch=powerpc karmic /mnt/ubuntu http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
  ```